# Error "Host x.x.x.x is not allowed to connect to this mariaDB server"

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a C# code that works with a database to save and manage data for a library, but when I try to connect, I get this error:

I've been following the following instructions to try to solve it, but none of them seem to fix the problem:

- https://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/sqlstatehy000-1130-host-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server?expand_article=1
- https://parzibyte.me/blog/2019/03/26/mysql-solucion-host-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mariadb-server/

Previously, I was working with the following code to declare the connection to the database, which was also throwing an exception due to an obsolete .toString() that I fixed. The code now looks like this:

```
public AccesoBD()
{
    try
    {
        servidor = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["192.168.60.54"];
        bdNombre = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["libreriawindowsform"];
        usuario = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["antonio"];
        contrasena = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[""];
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw;
    }
}

protected void abrirConexion()
{
    try
    {
        conexion = new MySqlConnection();
        conexion.ConnectionString = "Server=" + servidor + "; Database=" + bdNombre + "; Uid=" + usuario + "; Pwd=" + contrasena + ";SslMode=none;";
        conexion.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw;
    }

}
```

I would like to know how I can make the connection work properly. I have tried connecting via the terminal with my private IP and my username (which has no password), and the connection has been successful, so the problem likely comes from the C# side.

Also, the NuGet packages seem to be correct. I have attached a screenshot of the ones I have installed.

[image]
[image]

I've been following the following instructions to try to solve it, but none of them seem to fix the problem:

- https://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/sqlstatehy000-1130-host-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server?expand_article=1
- https://parzibyte.me/blog/2019/03/26/mysql-solucion-host-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mariadb-server/

Comment: Unrelated: `catch (exception ex) { throw; }` doesn't make sense. If you cannot handle them, let them bubble up. To your error: looks like (the message seems to suggest) your db is setup to use black/white listing. Check its configuration to allow connection from your machine.

Comment: Did you really named the settings after their *contents*? `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["192.168.60.54"];` is trying to load a setting named `192.168.60.54`. Try connecting with hard-coded settings to ensure you can connect. If you want to use AppSettings, create a *single* connection string setting and give it a meaningful name, eg `DbConnection`. There's an actual setting type for connection strings that allows testing the connection. If you want to store individual parameters, use names like `Server`, `User`, `Password

Comment: ^^ Is the parameter actually holding the correct value then? Did you verify that?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos yeah that was my problen I dont really understand that part of the code ty;

Comment: In that case you need a .NET Framework tutorial or docs. [Managing Application Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-application-settings-dotnet?view=vs-2022)